# multi time series correlation

Tags: c#, python, algorithm, wolfram-mathematica

I have a matrix[NxM] where N = 400 pixels and M = 5 different light levels (initial values).

1. For every light level, I have 400 light values corresponding to 400 pixels
2. The time series for different M values:
   [image: curves for different light levels]
3. The Blue line is saturated at the top and the rest of the series have a single maxima

How can I get an optimal M value such that it doesn't saturate (like blue) and also the maxima is in between a given range **(for example: 35000 - 37500)**

Present algorithm:

1. Initialize a series of **M** values: **[50, 100, 250, 350, 600]**
2. Foreach value of **M**: Read the maxima value of the time series and the corresponding Pixel Index
3. Perform polynomial fit (order=2) on the 5 **M** values and 5 Maxima values
4. Given a desired Maxima value, the polynomial fit should evaluate the corresponding **M** value.

This method requires a simple polynomial fit to work, where as the change in time series for each **M** value **may not be linear**. Hence I think a more accurate method should be written.

Is it possible I can use the data from these 4 time series to create a model and evaluate it to obtain an **M** value?

Any advise would be great.

Comment: What is an "M value"? Is this some mathematical parameter or what? Also, how is this related to programming, C# of Python? Apart from that, it's trivial to find the curve which has the maximum value within a certain range in pretty much any language.

Comment: M value is a DAC (digital to analog) value to an LED. So it is from 0 - 1023 or 0000 to FFFF. Which means higher the DAC value brighter the LED. I will edit the post with my present algorithm to show how it is related to programming.

Comment: But what are these values? Readings from a sensor? Also, your chart seems to have ~400 points, not 1024?

Comment: That was just for an example, it doesn't matter if it is 400 or 1024. The problem logic remains the same. Yes the values are read from a photodetector.

Comment: are you restricted to using only a few M values?  You could use `FindRoot` to dial in the exact maxima you want.

Comment: I know I can use find root to find the maximas or minimas, the question is how to find a relationship between different arbitrary M values and N values. So that a desired N value input should provide the corresponding M value.